# Can not run tests from non-root folder

Tags: go

I have a tests which looks like:

```
package tst

import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/demas/cowl-go/pkg/postgres"
    "log"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "github.com/demas/cowl-go/pkg/quzx-crawler"
    "github.com/SlyMarbo/rss"
    "time"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {

    prepare()
    retCode := m.Run()
    os.Exit(retCode)
}

func prepare() {
    connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s host=%s port=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        os.Getenv("DBUSER"),
        os.Getenv("DBPASS"),
        os.Getenv("DBHOST"),
        os.Getenv("DBPORT"),
        os.Getenv("DBNAME"))

    db, err := sqlx.Open("postgres", connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    db.Exec(`DELETE FROM Settings`)
    db.Exec(`DELETE FROM HackerNews`)
    // ....
}
```

Tests works fine if I keep in the root project folder, but if I move them to `tst` folder I get error message:

```
D:\development\gopath\src\github.com\demas\cowl-go\tst>go test -v
2017/03/31 16:30:06 sql: unknown driver "postgres" (forgotten import?)
exit status 1
FAIL    github.com/demas/cowl-go/tst    0.085s
```

Why ?

Comment: That error is because you haven't imported a sql driver. Did you intend to use "github.com/lib/pq", or is "github.com/demas/cowl-go/pkg/postgres" supposed to be a driver?

Comment: I have added `_ "github.com/lib/pq"` but the error remains.

Comment: Does any one of those dependencies maybe attempt to open a connection, without first importing `_ "github.com/lib/pq"`? Inside an `init` func or a func call setting a global `var`?

Comment: @mkopriva, thanks - it helps me. but why it worked fine from root of the project ?

Comment: @demas that's hard for me to tell without knowing the contents of the root folder at the time when it was working :)

Comment: @mkopriva, thank you. can you create an answer to the question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned by @JimB in the comments, the error means that you're trying to open a db connection, using `sqlx.Open`, without first importing a db driver. This can be fixed by, in your case, adding this `_ "github.com/lib/pq"` import spec.

If, even after adding that import, you're still seeing the same error, then that means that one of your dependencies is also trying to open a db connection without first importing the necessary driver.

Please note that while `log.Fatal` is a nice and clean way to stop your program it can sometimes be lacking, as you already know. You might want to consider using `panic` instead, its output is much more chaotic but, on the other hand, you'll get the line number and file name that caused the panic and eventually you'll learn to parse it quickly.